# Rewrite SQL code SELECT block to simplify logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-performance

I am trying to rewrite this block with simpler logic if this can be done. I am using it within a larger `SELECT` statement and I think IF I can simplify this block, I might be able to improve performance of my query.

`proj_catg_type_id`, `proj_catg_id` and `proj_id` are all PKs in their tables.

```
select  t1.proj_catg_name
from    table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
where   t2.proj_catg_type_id = t1.proj_catg_type_id
and     t2.proj_catg_type_id = 213
and     t3.proj_id = t2.proj_id
```

Comment: What does `t3` reference?

Comment: That's pretty simple as it stands, other than the non-ANSI join. Where did `t3` come from? Have you looked at the execution plan to see if there's any poorly performing sections?

Comment: You may want to look into the syntax for inner joins.  A good query optimizer should handle your syntax and an explicit inner join the same way, but I wouldn't assume SQL Server has a good query optimizer.  Other than that, this is a pretty basic query and I don't see any way to improve it.

Comment: make sure all the keys are indexed... look at the explain plan

Comment: t3 is another table in the dbs, should've included it in the from statement as table3 t3

Comment: @randy, SQl server deosn't have explain plans, it has execution plans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the referential integrety rules and the logic behind the tables it is difficult to give a 100% correct answer. But just by looking to this statement the most simplified logic would be

```
select t1.proj_catg_name
from    table1 t1
where   t1.proj_catg_type_id = 213;
```

Comment: but there are records where
t2.proj_catg_type_id != t1.proj_catg_type_id

Comment: Ok, understood. if you need this relationship then I thinky your query cannot be simplified. It is already very simple for joining 3 tables

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.proj_catg_name
from    table1 t1 inner join table2 t2     
on   t2.proj_catg_type_id=t1.proj_catg_type_id
where t2.proj_catg_type_id=213
and t3.proj_id=t2.proj_i
```

maybe? is t3 used outside this subselect?

Comment: yes it is, but am planning to do a :
from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3

Comment: @camelbrush, NEVER use implied syntax, it is a VERY POOR technique and a SQL antipattern. Please come into the current century with your code.

Answer (score -2):

If t3 is a table outside the selct you showed, then this is a correlated subquery which you should not be using at all, ever! That turns your query into a row-by agonizing row cursor.

Use derived tables or joins to get the results.

You don't give me enough code to write a specific solution for your problem, but let me give you an example:

```
SELECT 
      field1
    , field2
    , (SELECT t3.field3 
        FROM table2 t2 
        JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
        WHERE t4.somefield = t2.somefield)
FROM table1 t1
JOIn table4 t4 ON t1.id = t4.id

SELECT 
      field1
    , field2
    , t3.field3 
FROM table1 t1
JOIn table4 t4 
    ON t1.id = t4.id
join (SELECT field3 
        FROM table2 t2 
        JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id) a
    ON  t4.somefield = t2.somefield
```

The first query runs one row at a time which is extremely slow. The second should give the same results but runs in a set-based fashion which is much faster. It is important to make sure the derived table has an a alias. You could also use a CTE.

Comment: BTW, you used implied join syntax which is a very poor programming technique and a SQL antipattern. It is also more than 20 years out of date. You need to learn how to use explicit joins as you will make fewer mistakes and the code will be easier to maintain. (You will never again have to ask if the developer meant to use a cross join or it is was a mistake for instance.)

Comment: sorry but I can't follow what you are trying to suggest. 
Can you please make it a little more simpler?

Comment: I think this answer is no longer relevant (if it ever was!)